# what is NaN? and how is been created?

Tags: java, nan

I have  a `double[]` and it has a value which is `NaN`. When I add up the array's elements, the `NaN` makes the result `NaN` too.

How did it happen? How can I prevent this `NaN` from being added to the rest of my array?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN

Comment: Question shows complete lack of even attempting research.

Comment: @Ray i know what is NaN, if u read the question, u can see i asked about how to prevent adding NaN to the rest of array...wanna say my knowledge is law, im not afraid, its ok to me, by time passes i improve myself, any problem? :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[`NaN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) stands for Not-a-Number. It can [arise in a variety of ways](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Creation), for example as a result of `0./0.`, `sqrt(-1)`, or as the result of a calculation involving other `NaNs`.

The easiest way to check whether `v` is a `NaN` is by using [`Double.isNaN(v)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#isNaN%28double%29):

```
public static double sum(double arr[]) {
  double sum = 0.0;
  for (double val : arr) {
    if (!Double.isNaN(val)) {
      sum += val;
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
```

**edit:** @Stephen C makes a good point in the comments: before deciding to ignore that `NaN`, it would be prudent to understand where it came from. It could be that it is the result of a bug elsewhere in your code, and by blindly ignoring the `NaN` you could simply be masking the bug instead of fixing it.

Comment: Nice advice ... but also dangerous.  If you ignore NaN's without understanding where they came from, you run the risk of hiding bugs in your program and producing invalid output.

Comment: @StephenC: Good point, thanks. I've edited the answer to include a note to that effect.

Answer (score 4):

NaN stands for "Not a Number", so "Not A Number"  + 10 = "Not a Number"

You might want to consider debuggin your app to find what's in the double array :)

Comment: its an array which i created to store results of a mathematical formula, then it happened to be a NaN in the array, so any way to delete this NaN?

Comment: this answer seems legit http://stackoverflow.com/a/8971425/883671

Answer (score 3):

> how can i prevent that this NaN not bein added to the rest of my double[]

This way:

```
double[] array = something;
double sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (!Double.isNaN(array[i])) {
    sum += array[i];
  }
}
```

Comment: Though technically correct, encouraging the OP to ignore a NaN value in a mathematical program is ***not*** a good idea!

Comment: @Perception: Whether or not ignoring NaNs makes sense depends on the problem at hand. You could - in some contexts - think of NaN as empty Excel cells. When calculating sum over a range of cells, Excel treats empty cells as zeros, which is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: You've drawn an incredibly thin edge case based on the shaky assumption that a Java sentinel value is akin to a spreadsheet cell. I have yet to see a definition of NaN that equates it to zero, which is a perfectly valid number.

Comment: @Perception: Who said that zero is not a perfectly valid number, or that NaN is zero? *Ignoring* NaNs is totally different from *treating them as zeros*. In a sum, ignoring happens to be the equal to adding zero `(x+0=x)`, but in the generic case, e.g. when calculating average, it would be different: you just don't count the NaNs. In fact, that's what NaNs were originally invented for: representing missing values.

Answer (score 1):

### RTFM:

Javadoc for [NaN](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#NaN)

> `public static final double NaN` 
> A constant holding a Not-a-Number (NaN) value of type double. It is equivalent to the value returned by Double.longBitsToDouble(0x7ff8000000000000L).

And [relevant section of the JVM spec](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Instructions2.doc3.html) says any operation involving a `NaN` is *also* a `NaN` (a bit like a `null` in SQL)

Answer (score 1):

You can't just ignore the NaN, it's an indicator of a problem with you're program. You need to find out what is causing the NaN and fix that.

Answer (score 0):

NaN - Not a Number

btw try :

```
double[] array = new double[10];
String result = StringUtils.join(array);
System.out.println(result+ " BATMAN !");
```

Answer (score 0):

Java isn't my strong suit, but in other languages this comes from assigning a value from a string. Try this:

parseDouble

```
public static double parseDouble(String s)
                          throws NumberFormatException
```

Returns a new double initialized to the value represented by the specified String, as performed by the valueOf method of class Double.
Parameters:
s - the string to be parsed.
Returns:
the double value represented by the string argument.
Throws:
NumberFormatException - if the string does not contain a parsable double.
Since:
1.2
See Also:
valueOf(String)

Taken from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/).

Comment: The `parseDouble()` does not produce `NaN` values ... unless you try to parse the String `"NaN"`.  If you attempt to parse an invalid number string, you get an exception, not a `NaN`.